# JavaScript: How can I do something like `throw new Error()`, but without logging it in the console and stopping the whole running file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

`throw new Error()` logs an error and stops the running file, right? I want to do something similar to throwing error, but I want the file to still keep running, like if you do normal console.log. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `console.error('Omg that failed');` ?

Comment: It only stops execution if you forget to handle the error, otherwise your script will continue to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`try...catch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). If the code in the try block throws an exception then the code in the catch block will be executed. Then execution continues on afterwards.

```js
let somethingElse = function() {
  alert('something else')
}

try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  // expected output: ReferenceError: nonExistentFunction is not defined
  // Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
  somethingElse()
}

console.log('after')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the entire main function inside a try catch block:

```js
function main() { ... }

try {
  main();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('There was a critical error while running the app');
  console.error(error);
}
```